# rospkg.common.ResourceNotFound: catkin

Tags: ros, catkin, rospkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am facing this error suddenly in manipulating my dynamixel-based arm. Please anybody help me out. I have not changed anything since my previous version. But suddenly this problem occured. In the dynamixel_controller package:-

```
 File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/fuerte_workspace/dynamixel_motor/dynamixel_controllers/nodes/controller_manager.py", line 51, in <module>
    roslib.load_manifest('dynamixel_controllers')
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 62, in load_manifest
    sys.path = _generate_python_path(package_name, _rospack) + sys.path
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 98, in _generate_python_path
    packages = get_depends(pkg, rospack)
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 51, in get_depends
    vals = rospack.get_depends(package, implicit=True)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 201, in get_depends
    s.update(self.get_depends(p, implicit))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 201, in get_depends
    s.update(self.get_depends(p, implicit))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 195, in get_depends
    names = [p.name for p in self.get_manifest(name).depends]
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 133, in get_manifest
    return self._load_manifest(name)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 172, in _load_manifest
    retval = self._manifests[name] = parse_manifest_file(self.get_path(name), self._manifest_name)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 164, in get_path
    raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)
****rospkg.common.ResourceNotFound: catkin
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros****
================================================================================REQUIRED process [smartarm_motor_manager-1] has died!
process has died [pid 25712, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/fuerte_workspace/dynamixel_motor/dynamixel_controllers/nodes/controller_manager.py __name:=smartarm_motor_manager __log:=/root/.ros/log/0a8093ee-8f70-11e2-9c78-00224d6bc6e5/smartarm_motor_manager-1.log].
log file: /root/.ros/log/0a8093ee-8f70-11e2-9c78-00224d6bc6e5/smartarm_motor_manager-1*.log
Initiating shutdown!
================================================================================

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/fuerte_workspace/dynamixel_motor/dynamixel_controllers/nodes/controller_spawner.py", line 50, in <module>
    roslib.load_manifest('dynamixel_controllers')
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 62, in load_manifest
    sys.path = _generate_python_path(package_name, _rospack) + sys.path
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 98, in _generate_python_path
    packages = get_depends(pkg, rospack)
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 51, in get_depends
    vals = rospack.get_depends(package, implicit=True)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 201, in get_depends
    s.update(self.get_depends(p, implicit))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 201, in get_depends
    s.update(self.get_depends(p, implicit))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 195, in get_depends
    names = [p.name for p in self.get_manifest(name).depends]
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 133, in get_manifest
    return self._load_manifest(name)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 172, in _load_manifest
    retval = self._manifests[name] = parse_manifest_file(self.get_path(name), self._manifest_name)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 164, in get_path
    raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)
rospkg.common.ResourceNotFound: catkin
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
[smartarm_controller_spawner-2] killing on exit
[smartarm_motor_manager-1] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58437/rospkg.common.resourcenotfound:-catkin/) by [jontromanab](https://answers.ros.org/users/2662/jontromanab/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2013-03-18

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2013-03-20**:
I'm facing the same error message just a couple of days when building packages that use dynamic_reconfigure on fuerte (gen_cfg() fails): Strangely "roscd catkin" works while "rospack find catkin" fails. "source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash" did not help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Something in your launch file depends on `catkin` and rospkg cannot find it.

Make sure you have run `source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash` first.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jontromanab](https://answers.ros.org/users/2662/jontromanab/) on 2013-03-27**:
Hii.........thanks for the answer........it just worked for me.....the problem was in the ~/.bashrc file....sometimes it shows that problem I have mentioned, when there is two setup.bash file located in that file for different locations